# How can I add a search function the data below (Ideally in another component)

Tags: reactjs

How can I add a search function the data below (Ideally in another component, Nav Component)? I have tried passing the data via props and context and simply can not get it to work. I need to be able to filter through the data by Album name, Artist or potentially another attribute.

```
import React, { Component, useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
import '../components/data.css';


function Data() {
    const [Music, setMusic] = useState([], {});
useEffect(() => {
  axios.get('https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topalbums/limit=100/json')
  .then((data) => {
    setMusic(data.data.feed.entry);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
},[]);


    return (
        <div>
            <article className="albums">
             <ul className="album-items">
                {Music.map(Music => {
                const  { id, name, label, title, artist, entry } = Music;
                return (
                <div className="album" >   
                <li className='album-list' key={id.attributes['im:id']}>
                <h3 className='title'>Album Name: {Music['im:name'].label}</h3>
                <img src={Music['im:image'][2].label} alt={Music['im:name'].label}/>
                <h4 className='title'>Artist: {Music['im:artist'].label}</h4>
                </li>   
                </div>
                );
                })}
            </ul>
            </article>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can search the album data based on `album name` and `artist name`.

**Working App: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ww3afz)**

[image]

```js
import React, { Component, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function Data() {
  const [Music, setMusic] = useState([], {});
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topalbums/limit=100/json")
      .then(data => {
        setMusic(data.data.feed.entry);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }, []);

//======================================

  const handleSearch = event => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    setSearch(event.target.value.toLowerCase());
  };

  const filtered = Music.length
    ? Music.filter(
        music =>
          music["im:name"]["label"].toLowerCase().includes(search) ||
          music["im:artist"]["label"].toLowerCase().includes(search)
      )
    : [];

//======================================

  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={handleSearch} placeHolder={"search title, artist"} />
      <article className="albums">
        <ul className="album-items">
          {filtered.map(Music => {
            const { id, name, label, title, artist, entry } = Music;
            return (
              <div className="album">
                <li className="album-list" key={id.attributes["im:id"]}>
                  <h3 className="title">
                    Album Name: {Music["im:name"].label}
                  </h3>
                  <img
                    src={Music["im:image"][2].label}
                    alt={Music["im:name"].label}
                  />
                  <h4 className="title">Artist: {Music["im:artist"].label}</h4>
                </li>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
      </article>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Data;
```

Comment: Thanks! Any ideas on how I can pass this to another component?

Comment: It's easy, just pass the data and functions through props. depends on how you fragment your component tree.

Comment: Trust me it is not easy, I've spent  days trying to figure out how to do it. function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <GlobalStyles />
    <Nav />
    <Data />
    </>
  );
}

Comment: It's easy, the fact is that you don't know it yet :D Do post what have you tried I will help you fix it.

Comment: should I post it on another question?

Comment: That will be good. Do post what you have tried up until now. It will be an easy fix. also if possible, host your project on either Condesandbox or Stackblitz.

Comment: it wont let me add another question for 1 and half hours -https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-lewin-8likq?file=/src/app.css

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229401/discussion-between-ketan-ramteke-and-seanmarc).